# show lambda is an eigenvalue of matrix A and find one eigenvector x

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello Lovely people of the Overflow :)

I am working on a homework assigntment for my linear algebra class and i am stumped on this pesky question which is as follows:

Show that λ is an eigenvalue of A and find one eigenvector, x, corresponding to this eigenvalue.
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}6 & 6\\6 & -3\end{bmatrix},\qquad \lambda=-6.
$$

In my attempts I:

a) tired to find $A-6I$ (I being the identity matrix for $2\times2$ matrix)

b) The result of the above gave me the matrix :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}12 & 6\\6 & 3\end{bmatrix}
$$

From which i said that since Column 2 is 2x column 1 it is linear independent which implies null space is non zero. Now i am lost and do not know what to do. More so im not sure what to do next. My textbook does an example similar to this but i do not understand what steps it takes after this. Any suggestions , hints and helpful input is greatly appreciated :)

Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is given by $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, hence:

$$\lambda ^2-3 \lambda -54 = 0 \implies (\lambda +6)(\lambda -9) = 0 \implies\lambda_1 = -6, ~ \lambda_2 = 9$$

The eigenvectors are found by $[A - \lambda I]v_i = 0$. For $\lambda_1 = -6$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} 12 &\ 6\\ 6 & 3\\ \end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

The rref of this is:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&\dfrac{1}{2}\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

This gives us an eigenvector of:

$$v_1 = (-1, 2)$$

Of course, there are other possible choices for the eigenvector.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did you solve for the Characteristic polynomia ?

Answer (score 4):

Is this your matrix?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 6 \\
6 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The definition of the eigenvalue problem is as follows:

$$
Ax = \lambda x \rightarrow \left(A - \lambda \mathbb{I}\right)x = 0
$$

For that to have non-trivial solutions, the determinant of $A - \lambda \mathbb{I}$ must be zero--which basically just means subtracting $\lambda$ from each of the diagonals and setting the determinant to zero:

$$
det\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
6 - \lambda & 6 \\
6 & -3 - \lambda
\end{bmatrix}\right) = (6 - \lambda)(-3 - \lambda) - 36 = 0 \\
-18 - 6\lambda + 3\lambda + \lambda^2 - 36 = 0 \\
\lambda^2 - 3\lambda - 54 = (\lambda - 9)(\lambda + 6) = 0 \\
\lambda = 9, -6
$$

Now you go back to find the eigenvectors by solving each problem individually.

$\lambda = -6$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
12 & 6 \\
6 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} = 0 \\
12x + 6y = 0 \rightarrow y = -2x
$$

All this means is that the eignenvector is *any* vector such that the "y" component is the negative of twice the x, such as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It's particularly easy to find the eigenvector because it's a 2$\times$2 matrix.  Had it been a larger matrix, you would have to actually go through the steps of getting the matrix into reduced-echelon form (except for one row--usually).  The only thing that could make these problems more complicated is when you have a multiplicity (or degeneracy) in the eigenvalues which means there are multiple distinct eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Note that the eigenvectors are not unique.  All

Comment: Thankyou for your response Jared. I wish i had enough rep to upvote your answer aswell :)

In regards to your response i am curious how you went from matrix
|12 6||x|
|6  3||y| =0 to give you 12x+6y=0 -> y=-2x

I am assuming you multipiled the two matrices to give you 
|12x+6y|
|6x+3y |
But then how did you solve for y to be -2x?

Comment: I just took one of the two equations, either $12x + 6y = 0\rightarrow 6y = -12x$ or $6x + 3y = 0 \rightarrow 3y = -6x$.  That's what I was saying; since it's a 2$\times$2 matrix, you just have to solve one equation (as long as you get two distinct eigenvalues--which we did).